# Java equivalent of .net properties?

Tags: java, excel

I am looking to write a small application that reads information from an excel file, which we will use to update an xml.

I'm pretty well-verse in .net, where I would just simply create a new class with some properties to hold all of the values I am pulling from the excel file

```
Public Class HouseNoteInfo
    Private _MessageText As String

    Public Property MessageText() As String
        Get
            Return _MessageText
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _MessageText = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal msgText As String)
        _MessageText = msgText
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then I would simply create a list of the class, which I would be able to effectively keep data ordered and would be able to pull which items I wanted

```
Public NoteList As New Generic.List(Of HouseNoteInfo)
...
NoteList.Add(New HouseNoteInfo(msgText))
```

I've been trying to find an alternative for Java, but I don't believe they have the same getter/setter method as .net so I've only found I can create a HashMap of a new class containing my own methods to get and set the values but it feels clunky to me and was just wondering if there was a more efficient way to go about this?

Comment: I believe I don´t understand well your question, that code have a direct translation in Java in exactly the same way

Comment: Java doesn't have properties in the way that C# supports. You'd either have to use getters and setters or throw encapsulation aways and directly access the fields (make them public).

Answer (score 1):

```
public class HouseNoteInfo {

    private String messageText;
    private boolean enabled;  // to demonstrate getter/setter for booleans

    // constructor
    public HouseNoteInfo(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    // getter
    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    // setter
    public void setMessageText(String text) {
        this.messageText = text;
    }

    // getter for boolean prefixed with "is" instead of "get"
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    // setter
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled) {
        this.enabled = enabled;
    }

}

List<HouseNoteInfo> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new HouseNoteInfo("message text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have a property concept like that, but you can do the same with fields and methods. This would basically be the same:

```
public class HouseNoteInfo{

    private String messageText;

    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }

    public HouseNoteInfo(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use in this way in java

```
public class HouseNoteInfo {

    private String messageText;

    public HouseNoteInfo(String msg) {
        this.messageText = msg;
    }

    /**
     * @return the messageText
     */
    public String getMessageText() {
        return messageText;
    }

    /**
     * @param messageText the messageText to set
     */
    public void setMessageText(String messageText) {
        this.messageText = messageText;
    }   
}
```

and then

```
final List<HouseNoteInfo> noteList = new ArrayList<>();

...

noteList.add(new HouseNoteInfo(msg));
```